# TypeError when feeding tensorflow placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to feed a placeholder with following statements:

```
image = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape = (256,256))
image.eval(feed_dict={image, (image_)})
```

where image_ is:

```
array([[ 5, 12,  8, ..., 21,  2, 11],
       [ 5, 11, 13, ...,  9, 12,  4],
       [ 7,  2, 13, ...,  7,  9,  6],
       ..., 
       [ 1,  1,  6, ...,  8,  2,  4],
       [ 0,  2,  6, ...,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 4,  1,  4, ...,  9,  0,  5]], dtype=uint32)
```

And I am getting the error that:TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. Anyone has any ideas?

BTW, I am trying to load .mat file into tensor as images. Do i have better options?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant to use a `:` (colon) instead of `,` (comma)? In your example you feed a `set` as the `feed_dict` keyword argument, not a `dict`.

Comment: Great. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

feed_dict should be a dictionary, so you need to change the line

```
image.eval(feed_dict={image, (image_)})
```

into

```
image.eval(feed_dict={image:image_})
```

Comment: Many thanks. And I am wondering if I can build the graph with only feed.dict and run the graph with sess later? I think it is asking me for the session.

Comment: You could define the placeholder as part of building the graph. You don't need session for that. However, you must run the line image.eval(feed_dict={image:image_}) inside a session.